# Redirect subdomain to another subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

i want to know how could i redirect subdomain to another subdomain and also different domain name

for example

i want to redirect subdomain

```
forum.example.com
```

to

```
forum.example.net
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. you need to add a redirect to your .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [r=301,nc
```

Another good, but lazy way is to use the following link, to genereate the code for you [htaccesss generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://forum.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```