# redirect subdomain of a domain to another domain with pretty links

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I have two domains.
thingrate.com
modulgram.com

there is an app under mg.modulgram.com domain. There is a web.config file under this domain for rewrite rules. for example : mg.modulgram.com/orders/

I want to run this app under yasam.thingrate.com with pretty links. for example : yasam.thingrate.com/orders/

my app will be under of mg.modulgram.com domain only. I don't want to copy my app to yasam.thingrate.com.

is that possible and how can I do that?

Comment: This is not possible to answer with only the details you gave.   What type of application is it?  What webservers are you using?  What operating system?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Comment: both domains hosted on windows server...type of app is website...
what do you think about these questions asked on stackoverflow?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498200/redirect-subdomain-to-another-subdomain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765187/redirect-subdomain-of-one-domain-to-a-subdomain-of-another-domain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459685/redirect-all-subdomains-of-a-domain-to-an-other-domain

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984804/redirect-subdomain-to-another-domain

not asked on Webmasters...

Comment: Two of those are programming questions.  They have code and are answered with code.  One of them is closed.    You could add code to this question to make it a programming question, or you could ask in [webmasters.se].